# How to solve "Position Independant code" error with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, debian

I'm trying to compile some c++/Qt code on debian and I get following error :

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:1113:4: error: #error "You must build your code with position independent code if Qt was built with -reduce-relocations. " "Compile your code with -fPIC (-fPIE is not enough)."
# error "You must build your code with position independent code if Qt was built with -reduce-relocations. "\
```

The code has a makefile so and basically just executing the make command.

Please what can I do to solve this issue ? Thanks in advance !

Edit : Please find the code I am trying to compile https://github.com/juliendelile/MECAGEN

Comment: Please provide a code you are trying to run

Comment: It shows how you compile your and all the files you use to do it.

Comment: Try adding `-fPIC` to the `CFLAGS` variable on line 15 of `isf/Makefile`

Comment: Thanks everyone for trying to help. @Paul I think isf compiles without problems. Nevertheless, I did add -fPIC to the CFLAGS and I have got the same errors.

Comment: Hello Guys. Please can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem.

I just had to add -fPIC at line 50 of the makefile in mecagen/gui.

Thanks for your willingness to help.